# Unable to access user_tables table in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I am new to oracle. I have created the user axsaum in DB and logged in as the same user. When I try to access 
`select * from user_tables` or dba_tables 
its throwing error as table not exist
Please suggest me why i dont have privilege to access default tables?
how to access those?

```
SQL> select * from user_tables;
     * ERROR at line 1: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from dba_tables;
     * ERROR at line 1: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: Are you actually doing `from user_table` or from `from user_tables`? It might be helpful to edit your question to include exactly what you are running and the response you get, cut-and-pate from your client session (as text, not an image). You should also be able to see `all_tables`, but you won't be able to see `dba_tables` without extra privileges.

Comment: all predefined tables like user_tables,dba_tables,all_tables nothing i am not able to access. If extra privileges required, please suggest those?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give previliages to newly created user 
you can use `grant` for giving permission to user
once permission given you can see tables as well as can perfrom DML and DDL on DB

**for gratting previliages**

for all permissions you can use

`GRANT DBA TO axsaum ;`

For other permissions you use below

`GRANT CONNECT TO axsaum ;`

`GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE to axsaum`
is a system privilege grant that allows user to select from any Table or View.

`GRANT SELECT on some_table to axsaum`
is an object privilege grant that allows user to select from Table.

`GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON some_table TO axsaum;`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Issue is resolved post executed catlog.sql and catproc.sql files. Default data dictionaries are not create properly.